# json object to checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, json

I have this:

```
<div id="taglist">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkB1" id="chkB1" value="Mon" />&nbsp;Monday&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkB2" id="chkB2" value="Tue" />&nbsp;Tuesday&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkB3" id="chkB3" value="Wed" />&nbsp;Wednesday&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkB4" id="chkB4" value="Thu" />&nbsp;Thursday&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkB5" id="chkB5" value="Fri" />&nbsp;Friday&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkB6" id="chkB6" value="Sat" />&nbsp;Saturday&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkB7" id="chkB7" value="Sun" />&nbsp;Sunday&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="hidden" name="source_frequency" id="source_frequency" value="" />
</div>
```

And this:

```
var days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Sun"];
```

I want the values from days make the corresponding check boxes checked.  How would one do such a thing :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Sun"];

for(var day in days){
  $('#taglist input[value='+days[day]+']').prop("checked", true);
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var days = "Mon","Tue","Wed","Sun";
    var array=days.split(',');
    $(':checkbox').each(function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).val(), array)>=0)
    {
       $(this).attr('checked');
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like having a loop for your variable days

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Sun"]; //days array 
        for(var i=0;i<=days.length;i++){
           $('#taglist input[value='+days[i]+']').prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Sun"];

$(':checkbox[name^=chkB]').filter(function(index, val) {
    if(days.indexOf(this.value) >= 0)
        return this.checked = true;
});
```

**[Sample Workout](http://jsfiddle.net/6htkq/)**